# RTMP Stream Bitrate alternatives

Tags: actionscript-3, encoding, streaming, flash-media-server, rtmp

Which bit rates would you assign as **normal** and **high**?

**Quick Example:**

For the current project. On one hand I require a high quality stream (for full-screen). And of course, on the other it also has to be fast. The problem to solve is to balance it up to satisfy the most...

For the "high" option I would prioritize modern broadband with the around 2.5-3Mbits, to be able to deliver an almost perfect stream for the lucky ones having a > 4Mbits broadband connection (e.g. very common in Europe) without abusing the CDNs bandwidth.

For the "normal" option I would prioritize the slower broadband connections with something close to 1.2Mbits stream. If I go below 1Mbits the quality is just too poor and I'd rather use a progressive stream to make sure everybody is watching the video with a correct quality.

**So that's my plan for this particular case ... Any clever way to balance it up on an other way ? Any interesting (from your POV) user case ? An other perspective / way of thinking ? Any points to consider ? Opinions in general ? etc.**

Answer (score 0):

I would try 512Kbps for normal and 1Mbps for High.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean RTSP ?
Here in France we have a provider that is providing tv channels in RTSP, so that you can view it on a computer using VLC. 
I think the compression is MPEG-2, and the stream is around 3.5 / 4 MBs

Some channels are also available in HD, but I did not try it.
Be careful that people might have a good connection, but it can become quite loosy if they use Wifi.

You can google for RTSP + multiposte + freebox +bandwith and see if you can find some more information

Edit :
I don't think the protocol matters that much. I guess with H264 you can target lower rate than MPEG2. With an MP4 encoder doing live encoding (1 frame latency) What I consider medium quality was achieved at 1 Mbps on a Full-D1 video source. What do you mean by HD exactly ?

The question is not very clear yet, because there is two aspects :
What are the encoding sources and condition, what are the decoding resources.
This will give you a scale of bitrate vs visuals quality.

And then you have the problem of target audience and bandwidth and the quality of service
you need.

Where is your bottleneck ?

Comment: Thanks for the imput, however this is flash related (for a website) so I'm talking RTMP actually, not RTSP.